# Getting biblatex-chicago to include year when citing something included in a book

Tags: xetex, memoir, biber, biblatex-chicago

Writing something where I need to cite a lot of letters and such from a book. I'd like to have the year these things were first published/written included, but the only way I've been able to get it to work is by using `bookinbook`. It kinda sorta works, but as you can see below it's very verbose and the year is printed in a confusing way:

[image]

What I'd prefer for the second entry was something like:

> Manuel Chrysoloras, Brev til Demetrius Chrysoloras, i *Giotto and the Orators* 
>   af Michael Baxandall, 1971. C. 1395, 150–52.

I don't know if that's the correct "Chicago" way of doing it, and it's not like it *must* be done in this specific way -- I'd just like something that has a reasonable level of detail.

I feel like I've gone through every `biblatex-chicago`, but I also feel like I'm missing something and that this should be easy. Help? Below is my M-not-really-working-E

## Main file

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber,isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

First sample citation\footcite{manuel}

Second sample citation\footcite{manuel2}

\end{document}
```

## jobname.bib

```
@bookinbook{manuel,
    author = {{Manuel 2. Palaiologos}},
    title = {Beskrivelse af tapet},
    pages = {148--49},
    crossref = {baxandall1971},
    year = {c. 1400},
}

@bookinbook{manuel2,
    author = {Chrysoloras, Manuel},
    title = {Brev til Demetrius Chrysoloras},
    pages = {150--52},
    year = {c. 1395},
    crossref = {baxandall1971},
}


@book{baxandall1971,
 author={Baxandall, Michael},
 title = {Giotto and the Orators},
 subtitle = {Humanist Observers of Painting in Italy and the Discovery of Pictorial Composition 1350-1450},
 year = {1971},
 publisher = {Oxford University Press},
 location = {Oxford, England},
 series = {Oxford-Warburg Studies},
 }
```

To be compiled with `xelatex` and `biber` ...

Comment: Although I do not know Danish or its typesetting conventions, that's a strange place to put the (approximate) year of the letter. It seems more appropriate to put it close to the letter itself, which (I'm guessing) is 'Brev til Demetrius Chrysoloras'. If so, two solutions suggest themselves: `title = {Brev til Demetrius Chrysoloras (c.\@ 1395)}, shorttitle = {Brev til Demetrius Chrysoloras},`. Or: `title = {Brev til Demetrius Chrysoloras}, titleaddon = {c.\@ 1395}`.

Comment: @jon: That seems to work! Now I just do `titleaddon = {c.\@ 1395}` and good ole `inbook` and it looks fine. One (very minor) thing is that the letter `c` should always be lowercase ... can I fix this easily?

Comment: Is it not by so by default? Or do you mean in the bibliography? It may be that `\DeclareFieldFormat[bookinbook]{titleaddon}{#1}` will solve your problem, but I'd have to look closer to be sure.

Comment: I mean in the bibliography. It's not a dealbreaker, but it looks nicer. Capital C looks like an abbreviation of a name, I think.

EDIT: Hurm, that string did not fix it. It's because it's after a period.

Comment: Maybe `titleaddon = {{}c.\@ 1395}` could save you (just a guess, I don't have the time to check right now).

Comment: Beautiful, @moewe!

Answer (score 2):

Look again at your bib-entries. First, you have the book:

```
@book{baxandall1971,
    author={Baxandall, Michael},
    title = {Giotto and the Orators},
    year = {1971},
 }
```

Here, you set the year to 1971. Now you crossreference it:

```
@bookinbook{manuel,
    author = {{Manuel 2. Palaiologos}},
    title = {Beskrivelse af tapet},
    pages = {148--49},
    crossref = {baxandall1971},
    year = {c. 1400},
}
```

Fields from the `book` entry are inherited by all `bookinbook` entries crossreferencing it, so you don't have to set fields like `bookauthor`, `booktitle` etc. in each `bookinbook` entry. Unfortunately, this prefixing (`title` of book becomes `booktitle` of texts in the book) does not work for all fields, e.g. `year`. By setting `year` in the `bookinbook` entries, you actually overwrite the year defined in the  `book` entry.

Now change the `bookinbook` entries like this:

```
@bookinbook{manuel,
    author = {{Manuel 2. Palaiologos}},
    title = {Beskrivelse af tapet},
    pages = {148--49},
    crossref = {baxandall1971},
    origyear = {c. 1400},
}
```

This does not overwrite the definition of `year` from the book, so even when it is crossreferenced, the book will keep its publication date and not be made some centuries older. :-)

By the way, section 2.3.8 (Date Specifications) from the current biblatex documentation says

> If there is no `date` field in an entry, `biblatex` will also consider the fields `year` and `month` for backwards compatibility with traditional BibTeX.

Using `year` and `origyear` will work, but the modern way is to replace it with `date` and `origdate`. The change is not just cosmetically; with `date` you can specify dates following the yyyy-mm-dd scheme and even ranges. The `date` field is dissected internally, so styles can still access the individual data (`year`, `month`, and `day`;  in ranges also `endyear`, `endmonth`, and  `endday`).